# Plot a map using lat and long with R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, cluster-computing

I have a dataframe with latitude and longitude coordinates for all the places (4500 cities) I want to plot.

For example:

| CITY | lat | long | cluster |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | -16.75881189 | -49.44054783 | 1 |
| B | -18.48756496 | -47.39683244 | 2 |
| C | -48.71881214 | -16.18267186 | 3 |

I need something like this - But here it teaches how to do using python and I need to use R. (FROM: https://www.kaggle.com/crisparada/brazilian-cities-a-simple-exploration):

[image]

However, I could not find on internet how I can plot in R using coordinates. The only thing i found is how i can get the coordinates on google maps and then plot direclty. But, since I have to do a kind of "scatterplot map" for more than 4500 cities it is not pratical do in this way.

I recently started studying R language and there are some interpretations that I cannot make in relation to what I find on the internet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try using the `sf` package.

Assuming you've already loaded the data from a .csv or other type, and have a dataframe (or tibble) named `my_df`:

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

my_sf <- st_as_sf(my_df, coords = c('LON', 'LAT'))

my_sf <- st_set_crs(my_sf, crs = 4326)

#Plot it:

ggplot(my_sf) + 
  geom_sf(aes(color = cluster))
```

The sf package (and associated `geom_sf`) is R's way of plotting geographic data.  4500 points shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: It seems to be working, @mrhellmann! Thanks. But it looks like something still needs to be adjusted ...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBC3h.png

Comment: @user14738548 change the order of LAT and LON in the `st_as_sf` function.  As edited above.

Comment: What is `crs = 4326`?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- `EPSG:4326 - WGS 84, latitude/longitude coordinate system based on the Earth's center of mass, used by the Global Positioning System among others.`

Comment: @mrhellmann Thanks, are you quoting from somewhere?